# Firefox EXTENSION_ID_REQUIRED on manifest.json

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, manifest.json, web-extension, web-ext

I've recently built a script extension for Chrome using [Manifest Version 3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/), and it's been working smoothly. Now, I'm attempting to create a Firefox version of the same extension. To do this, I'm using the [web-ext](https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext) tool, specifically version 7.6.2.

However, during the process of running the command `$ web-ext lint`, I encountered a critical error:

| Code | Message | Description | File |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EXTENSION_ID_REQUIRED | The extension ID is required in Manifest Version 3 and above. | See [this link](https://mzl.la/3PLZYdo) for more information. | `manifest.json` |

I've tried to find examples of `manifest.json` files that utilize Manifest Version 3 on the official [MDN GitHub repository](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples). However, it appears that the majority of the provided examples are based on Manifest Version 2

One specific point that's not entirely clear to me is whether the ID for the Firefox extension is generated automatically by the platform or if I need to provide my email address as the ID.

Comment: The "this link" in the error says you need to add [browser_specific_settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_specific_settings) to manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm Well, I require a distinct email for each extension I create, and then convert them all into GUID format. Is it not achievable with web-ext? Because the extension key for Chrome is automatically generated by Chrome

Comment: The link describes the only possible solution. Their documentation for extensions is usually up-to-date.